How to get pre loaded pages from pager?
So I have a simple pager implementation, I would like to create a scrollable calendar with dynamic day content.
Here is my code:
val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {
        36
    })

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                columns = GridCells.Fixed(7),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
            ) {
                items(
                    items = calendarDaysData,
                    key = { item: CalendarDayData -> item.dayNumber }) { d ->
                    CalendarDay(
                        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red),
                        calendarDayData = d
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

The main idea is to create a pager with 36 pages, that represents 36 month. One time just one month data is visible.
The data what I want to show, comes from the database by the current day, but I don't want to store and query all days data one time, instead of that, I would like to query just for example 5 to 6 day data, because one time 1 day will be visible, and there will be the next and previous x day data in the memory, if the user scrolls.
Pager uses Lazy creation, what I would like to take an advantage of.
So I don't know how to implement this behavior, as far as I know, pager loads just a few page data, and changes after every scroll. If I knew the "pre loaded" pages indexes, I could load the data every time, so the user doesn't have to wait to the data.
Unfortunately I haven't found yet how should I get this data from pager.

Why store a calendar in a database when it can be easily computed at runtime?

Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, I calculate the the calendar data, but I store the events in the database, so I the current month is August I need to get the events for August, and show something in the respective day.

OK, the question isn't clear to me. If you're trying to preload a certain number of pages, you can do that using the beyondViewportPageCount parameter. Check out this YouTube video

Thanks, exactly I want to do that, I'll check it

As pointed out in the comments, you can use the beyondViewportPageCount parameter offered by the HorizontalPager Composable.
HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState,
    beyondViewportPageCount = 1,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    //...
}

By default, the HorizontalPager will use the constant PagerDefaults.BeyondViewportPageCount which is 0. In your case, it should be sufficient to set the value to 1:
@Composable
fun Calendar() {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {
        36
    })

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        beyondViewportPageCount = 1,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) { pageIndex ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = "PAGE $pageIndex")
        }
        Log.d("Calendar", "Loading page $pageIndex...")
    }
}

Note that the HorizontalPager also has a second mechanism that loads pages in advance, which is the LazyLayout prefetching. So it can happen that the HorizontalPager actually prefetches more pages than you specified in the beyondViewportPageCount parameter:

You can think of beyondBoundsPageCount as a guarantee that the given
number of pages will be composed on both sides of the active page no
matter if the pager is scrolling or stopped.

Demo:
If you start the app on page 0, you will see the following log outputs:
2024-08-12 08:47:45.801  5836-5836  Calendar  D  Loading page 0...
2024-08-12 08:47:45.883  5836-5836  Calendar  D  Loading page 1...

After swiping to the right once to page 1, you will see the following logs:
2024-08-12 08:57:23.647  6906-6906  Calendar  D  Loading page 2...
2024-08-12 08:57:23.675  6906-6906  Calendar  D  Loading page 3...  // this is LazyLayout prefetching

